# How to decode variable from json when key is changing according to user input?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable, jsondecoder

I am trying to parse some JSON response coming from [CoinmarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) using the `JSONDecoder()` in Swift 4. But the problem is that the response from json is changing according to user input. e.g if user wants the price in eur, the output is following:

```
[
    {
        "price_eur": "9022.9695444"
    }
]
```

but if user wants the price in gbp:

```
[
    {
        "price_gbp": "7906.8032145"
    }
]
```

So the question is how should I make the struct that inherits from `Decodable` if the variable(json key) name is changing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can decode the dynamic key by creating a custom `init(from:)` method for your struct, then using two set of coding keys, an `enum` containing all keys that are known at compile time and another `struct` that you initialize using the dynamic keys that are generated using user input (contain the name of the currency).

In your custom `init(from:)` method you just need to decode each property using their respective keys.

```
let chosenCurrency = "gbp"

struct CurrencyResponse: Decodable {
    let name:String
    let symbol:String
    let price:String
    private static var priceKey:String {
        return "price_\(chosenCurrency)"
    }

    private enum SimpleCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, symbol
    }

    private struct PriceCodingKey : CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: SimpleCodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        symbol = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .symbol)
        let priceValue = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PriceCodingKey.self)
        price = try priceValue.decode(String.self, forKey: PriceCodingKey(stringValue:CurrencyResponse.priceKey)!)
    }
}

do {
    let cryptoCurrencies = try JSONDecoder().decode([CurrencyResponse].self, from: priceJSON.data(using: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Test JSON:

```
let priceJSON = """
    [
    {
    "id": "bitcoin",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "rank": "1",
    "price_\(chosenCurrency)": "573.137",
    "price_btc": "1.0",
    "24h_volume_\(chosenCurrency)": "72855700.0",
    "market_cap_\(chosenCurrency)": "9080883500.0",
    "available_supply": "15844176.0",
    "total_supply": "15844176.0",
    "percent_change_1h": "0.04",
    "percent_change_24h": "-0.3",
    "percent_change_7d": "-0.57",
    "last_updated": "1472762067"
    },
    {
    "id": "ethereum",
    "name": "Ethereum",
    "symbol": "ETH",
    "rank": "2",
    "price_\(chosenCurrency)": "12.1844",
    "price_btc": "0.021262",
    "24h_volume_\(chosenCurrency)": "24085900.0",
    "market_cap_\(chosenCurrency)": "1018098455.0",
    "available_supply": "83557537.0",
    "total_supply": "83557537.0",
    "percent_change_1h": "-0.58",
    "percent_change_24h": "6.34",
    "percent_change_7d": "8.59",
    "last_updated": "1472762062"
}
]
"""
```

Comment: That is a awesome answer, thank you very much. As I understand then the "chosenCurrency" has to be a global variable then?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp no worries, glad I could help. No, `chosenCurrency` doesn't actually need to be a global variable, you can define it anywhere as long as you can access it both from the initializer of `CurrencyResponse` and from your viewcontroller class, where the user input is coming from. I just tested my code in a playground, so this was the easiest solution for defining `chosenCurrency`.

Comment: Adding `chosenCurrency` outside of the `struct` is not working very well. For instance, if you want to parse in `tableview` it will be late in updating `chosenCurrency`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a small number of possible keys, you can do the following

```
struct Price: Decodable {

    var value: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case price_eur
        case price_gbp
        case price_usd
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .price_eur)
        } catch {
            do {
                value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .price_gbp)
            } catch {
                value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .price_usd)
            }
        }
    }
}

let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["price_gbp": "10.12"], options: [])
let price = try JSONDecoder().decode(Price.self, from: data)
```

Otherwise, you will need to parse data manually.

Comment: You don't actually need to parse the data manually, it is possible to use dynamic keys while still conforming to the `Codable` protocol. See my answer on how to do it.