# Parse JSON with variable keys

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm trying to parse JSON with currency rates contains dynamic keys and a dynamic number of values. Output depends on input parameters, such as Base currency and several currencies to compare.

Example of JSON:

```
{
"USD_AFN": 70.129997,
"USD_AUD": 1.284793,
"USD_BDT": 82.889999,
"USD_BRL": 3.418294,
"USD_KHR": 4004.99952
}
```

, or:

```
{
"EUR_CAD": 0.799997
}
```

Also, I should be able to change Base currency and currencies to compare, and change number of currencies to compare.
I already tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422653/how-to-decode-variable-from-json-when-key-is-changing-according-to-user-input).

What is the optimal way to handle it?

Thanks

**Additional info**

So, I made the struct without the initializer

```
struct CurrencyRate: Codable { 
var results : [String:Double] 
}
```

and trying to decode it

```
 do { let results = try decoder.decode(CurrencyRate.self, from: dataToDecode) print(results) } catch { print("Error") }
```

I'm still getting the error.

Eventually, I just need an array of currency rates (values) to populate it in a Table View.

Comment: I'd keep the dictionary (decode into `[String:Double]`)

Comment: I tried to use this struct 

`struct CurrencyRate: Codable {
  
  var results : [String:Double]
  
  init(results: [String:Double]) {
    self.results = results
  }`

and

`let results = try decoder.decode(CurrencyRate.self, from: dataToDecode)`

, but it catching an error. 

Probably my struct is not correct for this situation?

Comment: Is this the entire JSON? If yes the code is supposed to work. You don't need the initializer in the struct, not even without conforming to `Codable`

Comment: Yes, this is the entire JSON, but it may contain any number of objects and any combination of keys (XXX_XXX).
So, I made the struct without the initializer `struct CurrencyRate: Codable {
  
  var results : [String:Double]
}` and trying to decode it `do {
  let results = try decoder.decode(CurrencyRate.self, from: dataToDecode)
  print(results)
} catch {
  print("Error")
}`
I'm still getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is a bad idea to put more than a line of code into a comment. Add it to the question if you like to do it that way. Your `JSON` is lacking the `results` key which is why it would not parse. Currently your `JSON` is a simple hash `[String:Double]` which could be decoded even with a `JSONSerializer`. However your question of "optimal" bares the (usual) question: "What do you want to do (with it)?"

Comment: I put additional info in the question body. Could you please provide a code snippet how to use JSONSerializer in this case? 
Thanks

Comment: *I'm still getting the error.* What error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation my Playground looks as follows:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

let jsonData = """
{
"USD_AFN": 70.129997,
"USD_AUD": 1.284793,
"USD_BDT": 82.889999,
"USD_BRL": 3.418294,
"USD_KHR": 4004.99952
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let obj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:jsonData, options:[])
    print(obj)          // this is an NSDictionary
    if let dict = obj as? [String:Double] {
        print(dict)     // This is not "just" a cast ... more than I thought
    }
}

struct CurrencyRate: Codable {
    var results : [String:Double]
}

// If you use a "results"-key it _must_ be present in your JSON, but it would allow to add methods
let resultsJson = """
{
  "results" : {
    "USD_AFN": 70.129997,
    "USD_AUD": 1.284793,
    "USD_BDT": 82.889999,
    "USD_BRL": 3.418294,
    "USD_KHR": 4004.99952
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let currencyRate = try JSONDecoder().decode(CurrencyRate.self, from: resultsJson)
    print(currencyRate)
}

// this is probably the easiest solution for just reading it
do {
    let rates = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Double].self, from:jsonData)
    print(rates)
}

// While you could do the following it does not feel "proper"
typealias CurrencyRatesDict = [String:Double]

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Double {
    func conversionRate(from:String, to:String) -> Double {
        let key = "\(from)_\(to)"
        if let rate = self[key] {
            return rate
        } else {
            return -1.0
        }
    }
}

do {
    let currRates = try JSONDecoder().decode(CurrencyRatesDict.self, from:jsonData)
    print(currRates)
    print(currRates.conversionRate(from:"USD", to:"AUD"))
}
```

This taught me a few things. I would not have thought that a `NSDictionary` (which is produced by `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` automatically and has no types) converts this easily into a `[String:Double]`, but of course it might fail and you should write some error handling to catch it.

Your `CurrencyRate` `struct` would have the advantage to allow easy extensions. Since Dictionaries are `structs` it is not possible to derive from them. As the last version illustrates it is possible to add a conditional extension to a `Dictionary`. However this would add your new function to *any* `Dictionary` matching the signature which might be acceptable in many cases even though it 'feels' wrong from the design perspective.

As you can see there is a whole bunch of ways to deal with this in Swift. I would suggest you use the `Codable` protocol and an additional key. Most probably there are "other things" you will want to do with your object.